# PHP HTML Show button properties

Tags: php, html, post, button

I would like to be able to get as many properties from a button to show as I can.

**The button:**

```
<input name="Accept" type="submit" class="button" id="Accept" value="Accept" />
```

**The button code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['Accept'])){
//show button properties here
}
```

**What I would like it to show on button press:**

- name: Accept
- type: submit
- class: button
- id: Accept
- value: Accept

and what ever else can be shown

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I know you might not be able to show all but I want to be able to show as much as I can

Comment: What is your use case for this? When POSTing, only the name and value of the input element will be sent.

Comment: The only data passed back on submit is the name and value pair. Unless you're open to using JavaScript.

Comment: So I know if I can do things with the properties. Example, if ID=5 do something.

Comment: Sam why do you need the id ? The name in this case will be unique for that input or should be at least.

Comment: Basically there are many buttons of the same type on the same form. I need to be able to give them different id or something to identify them when they are pressed.

Comment: Then you would to give them a different name (or different values), and this is the standard approach to problem

Comment: Come on you are not the first one with this problem that exists since the beginning of the web, why do buttons have names and values and why are they getting submitted if not for that reason?

Comment: BTW in the onSubmit function how do you know which button was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way how to get properties of HTML element by normal HTML behavior - but you can use JavaScript function that handles "onSubmit" form event by which you can send all you need.

Comment: Ok thanks. How about somthing like this...

name="save[11798779]"

How can I get the number from that?

Comment: Of course after that $_POST will contains key 'save' which is array with key '11798779' that will contains value of the original HTML element.

Comment: The simplest way is using `foreach` - if you don't know what number you looking for. Or if you know what you looking for use `array_key_exists` to check if the number is there.

Comment: Hmm could you give me an example?

Comment: Try this simple code: `<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><pre><?php var_dump($_POST);?></pre><form id="testform" action="" method="POST"><input name="Accept[asdfsd]" type="submit" class="button" id="Accept" value="Accept" /></form></body></html>` - save it as a `test.php` and run it and you will see.

Comment: Or this: `<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><pre><?php if(array_key_exists('Accept', $_POST)){foreach($_POST['Accept'] as $t => $x){echo $t . ' , ' . $x . ' , ' . $t[$x] . '<br/>';}}?></pre><form id="testform" action="" method="POST"><input name="Accept[asdfsd]" type="submit" class="button" id="Accept" value="Accept" /></form></body></html>
`.

Comment: How exactly do you send the info with JavaScript?

Comment: array(1) { ["Accept"]=> array(1) { ["asdfsd"]=> string(6) "Accept" } }

But how do I actually grab the "asdfsd"

Comment: How exactly do you send it with JavaScript? As of my knowledge JavaScript doesn't send any info unless you're using Ajax, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, by using XHR request - you simply add event handler on form's submit event and use your JavaScript code to send the data you want and than returns false in order to stop the default form sending behavior.

Comment: Then you would have to be more clear in your answer since this isn't the default behavior of onSubmit, also in my opinion this is the long way around, besides that for any user that has JavaScript disabled (and many mobile phones are) this will not work, and while I also support the use of Ajax it is not meant for something that has a standard approach with regular HTML.

Comment: Suppose you want to do an "if" in code and instead you are doing a while loop and breaking out after the first time, this is actually my attitude to this problem and the accepted solution

Comment: Also note that this will noy work if you wwnt to upload a file, at least not in HTML4

Comment: Also when submitting to a different host than the JavaScript source there might be problems because of the same origin policy and you will have to resort to JSONP

Comment: In fact I don't fully understand you ... that code I post is only exemplary and I think is fully understandable - it shows only possibilities on cases I was asked for. Nothing more.

Comment: What I have said is that the problem that he presented (either of determining the button pressed or sending extra information with the form) isn't something new and it existed since the beginning of the web before one even thought of JavaScript and of course not of ajax, and it is the underlying reason for hidden inputs and button names and values, and as such presenting an answer to bypass the form submission and use ajax is like advicing not to use a link but use instead a button which triggers a function that sets location.href... it is the long way around, and can also introduce problems

Comment: Sometimes beginners are getting very excited with the freedom that Ajax brings, but not always what you could do is what you should do, especially when the conventionial way provides it as well and ajax introduces problems and also makes the code less readable

Comment: In fact I don't understand you - I answered the question with pretending that listeners have some knowledge and willing to learn new things - all I've posted here was tested and correct.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way, without using javascript would be to store a copy of the data in the name of the element:

```
<input name="Accept" type="submit" class="button" id="Accept" value="Accept" />
```

becomes:

```
<input name="Accept.submit.button.Accept" type="submit" class="button" id="Accept" value="Accept" />
```

You can get the `value` from your `$_POST` array. For the rest of the properties, just split up the key of the element using `explode()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to submit properties of an input besides the name and value, however you can have hidden inputs on the form with whatever information you want, and you can even create them or populate them dynamically in the button's onclick even or the form's onsubmit event.

As another option I would stuff in the information in the button's value in JSON form, since the button's value usually anyway serves no purpose.

And if you are really out for ideas then you can stuff the info in the query string of the url in the action attribute of the form, and then get the info by checking the GET array (however if the form method is get instead of post then the values might get overwritten!)

But if yout problem is only that you need a way to distinguish between many buttons, then just have a different name or value for each of them, and this is probably the only reason why buttons have names and values.

Regarding andrejd's answer please note that while you can use the onSubmit function to to submit with Ajax and then return false to cancel the default submit, please note that the following problems exist with that approach:

1) That the onSubmit function doesn't know which button was pressed, however you can instead use the button's onClick event, but you will have to bind to every submit button on the form (you can do this much easier with jquery etc.)

2) Since Ajax does not affect the page content so ypu will refresh it on your own or navigate the page on your own, the latter can be done using "location.href"

3) If you are submitting files you will have a hard time doing it with ajax, you can try the use the jquery fileupload plugin.

4) Ajax is restricted to the same origin (something tgat form submittion isn't), you can try to workaround using JSONP.

5) Ajax will not work if the client doesn't have JavaScript (such as some mobile phones or some text browsers such as linux browsers) or has disabled JavaScript or is using an older browser, and in general it is not recommended to rely solely on Ajax but instead at least provide an alternative for these cases.

For problems 2-4 you can aldo solve them by having the Ajax just the extra content and then return true to let the default submission submit the form.

Comment: This is the standard way of doing these things in the stateless HTTP, and this is the reason for the existence of hidden inputs in the first place.

Comment: In fact ASP.Net is behind the scene almost based completely on this idea using the viewstate input

Comment: I edited my answer to add another possible way of doing it, still I would recommend to stick to the standard way of using hidden inputs