# How to link a textbox value to a database row and then insert it

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a textbox where it stores in a user's option. The possible options are options 3 all the way to 26, 'True or False' and 'Yes or No'.

```
<input type="text" name="gridValues" class="gridTxt maxRow" readonly="readonly" />
```

Now in my database I have a table known as 'Options' which contains an 'OptionId' and 'OptionType' fields. The rows in the table is like this below:

```
OptionId  OptionType
O1        A-C
O2        A-D
O3        A-E

...

O24       Yes or No
```

Now what I want to do if it is possible is that I want options 3-26 and options 'True or False' and 'Yes or No' from the application to link with an 'OptionId' from the database.

For example:

```
If textbox equals 3 then this equals OptionId 'O1'
If textbox equals 4 then this equals OptionId 'O2'
If textbox equals 5 then this equals OptionId 'O3'

...

If textbox equals Yes or No then this equals OptionId 'O24'.
```

I want this to happen because  when I INSERT VALUES, I want to INSERT the 'OptionId' in other database tables when I need to.

Is this possible to do and if so does anyone know how to link the textbox value to the 'OptionId' and then INSERT it into a database table known as 'Questions'?

Comment: wow this is one badly asked question.

Comment: In some form or another this has been asked on SO before and a simple google search will get you where you need to go faster.

Comment: This is my first question on SO, how have I asked this over and over again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem then you want to an insert in one table based on another table's value, this can be done with an INSERT SELECT as in

```
INSERT INTO questions SELECT optionid FROM options WHERE optiontype = $selected_option
```

Comment: Hi, I think something like this could work but what goes in the "selected_option" variable?

Comment: It should normally be something like $_POST["gridValus"], but from your question it doesn't look like the values directly map to the table values, and if this is the case then you may have to do it manully using a "switch case"

Comment: Can you show me an example of your code on a switch statement for 1 option, I can then use this to do it for the other options, it will be very helpful for me :)

Comment: I don't know how your values link to the optiontype in the database, but if option 3 links to a-c then do "case '3': $selected_value = 'A-C';break;", if you need help on the switch case syntex just google for it or check the PHP documentation

Comment: Hi, thanks for the switch statement example, I will see if I can get it to work and comment later on whether it has worked or not :). By the way the php code which will insert the values will be in a seperate page from the application so does the switch statement go on the same page as the query or where the textbox is?

Comment: If it works then just mark it as accepted (of course you can also comment if you have something more to add)

Comment: I don't know why you separated them on the first place so I can't really answer, but in general it depends if the code is unique to the page or it is global for all usages of the query (and for the later case I would even recommend you to have it instead as a column in the options table)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to link the textbox with the mysql row.

You will have to send an ajax request with a function attached on `onChange` event of the textbox to do this.

I am not going to cover the ajax part, but you can do something like this using jquery.

```
$("#yourtextbox").change(function() {
    var textval = this.value; //get the value
    $.post(
        "yourpage.php", //the page to update the text box based on the values
         { 
             'variablename': textval, 
             'action' : 'update' 
         }, //send the values
         function(data) {
             //do something on the success
         }
    );
});
```

Comment: can you show an example of ajax and onchange event, I never used ajax before

Comment: @user1309180, I made a simple example using jQuery. Check it out

Comment: He can submit the form without using Ajax, it doesn't appear from the question that he looks for a way to send it to the server, instead he wants a way to insert it into the database, but maybe I am wrong with this

Comment: @yohal: And just how does he get it from client-side to the database without sending it to the server?

Comment: Hi, I don't need to know how to submit the form what yo hal has commented, I just want to know that for example if the textbox is '3' how do I link that with 'OptionId' 'O1'? if textbox is '4', link that to 'OptionId' 'O2' and etc.

Comment: @Peter I already have jquery code which links up to another page nad that is where the database would go. I did not know that is actually known as AJAX but I found out from Starx's code that it is known as AJAX

Comment: @Peter many people forget that you can submit a form without using Ajax:)

Comment: I believe I misunderstood your original comment.  My point was that it has to be sent to the server somehow.  I guess you were suggesting that it might be done without AJAX?

Comment: My comment was two fold, one that it is probably not his problem, and in case it is there is no need for Ajax unless there is a reason for it see my post on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935165/php-html-show-button-properties/9935311#9935311 all the drawbacks of using Ajax instead of the conventional form submition